# SAS procedures Delete and Datasets

Tags: dataset, sas

I'm just learning sas and see two interesting procedures.

```
  proc Delete data = table;  run;
```

and

```
  proc datasets lib=Libr nolist;
        modify table;
           rename __first = second;
  quit;
  run;
```

and several questions about them:

1. why some procedures ended like `quit` not `run`?
2. why `datasets` use `quit` and `run` together? (is this a statement to quit table?)
3. is it best recommendation to use `datasets-procedure` for small tasks? (not, of course, but for what?  or doesn't use it?)
4. and also, which method is faster: `proc delete` or `sql-drop`? (which have a greater speed and on which amount of data it is necessary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Some `SAS` procedures end in `QUIT`, rather than `RUN`, because they are running in `Interactive Mode`. For instance, in `PROC GLM`, you can specify an additional model statement as long as the top of the `SAS` window says that `PROC GLM` is running (if you're using the `Windows` version).
2. Some programmers have gotten into the habit of typing `QUIT` and `RUN` together. I don't think it actually matters, as procedures that use the `QUIT` statement begin running as soon as you enter them. I only use one or the other.
3. `PROC DELETE` is an unsupported legacy feature; it has been officially superseded by `PROC DATASETS`, which is the designated tool for handling datasets in SAS. [Mailing List Post](http://www.listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind9703e&L=sas-l&P=1322).

I generally don't find myself with much need to delete datasets while in `SAS`. Because `SAS` effectively manages its memory use, and because RAM is so plentiful now, I usually do 90% of my work from temporary datasets which I create on-demand at the start of the session.

4. As before, `PROC DELETE` is now deprecated in favor of `PROC DATASETS`. In terms of which is faster, excluding extremely large data, I would wager that there is little difference between them. When handling permanent SAS datasets, however, I like to use `PROC DATASETS` rather than `PROC SQL`, simply because I feel better manipulating permanent datasets using the SAS-designed method, and not the `SQL` implementation (which isn't 100%) in my opinion.

Comment: How is the sql implementation not 100%?

Comment: There are a few things one can do in SQL that one cannot do in PROC SQL. The one that immediately comes to mind is changing the type of a variable.

Comment: Ah, I read it as `drop table` wasn't 100% in the SQL implementation.

Answer (score 3):

WRT "run" versus "quit":

Some SAS procedures support something called "run group processing", which means that the procedure performs whatever work it is asked to do when it sees the "run;" statement.  The procedure continues to execute until it sees a "quit:" statemnet.  In fact, a "quit;" statement will automatically insert a "run;" statement if there is still work to be done.

PROC DATASETS is one of those procedures.  The "quit;" statement says that there is no more work for the procedure to do.  Consider this trivial example:

```
proc datasets;
   change a=new_a;
run;
   delete new_a;
run;
quit;
```

The first statement (change) renames an existing dataset "a" to  "new_a".  The second statement will delete that dataset.  If you fail to include a "run;" statement (after "change") in this example, the procedure will fail because it will notice that the "new_a" dataset does not exist and so will not execute either statement.

That said, I rarely use PROC DATASETS myself; I prefer to use PROC SQL.

WRT: PROC DELETE versus DROP TABLE with PROC SQL:

Although PROC DELETE is officially "deprecated", all that means is that it will no longer be changed.  It is a simple procedure to delete a data object from a SAS library; I use it all the time.  It has one special advantage compared to PROC SQL.  If you use PROC DELETE to try and delete a dataset that does not exist, you will just get a warning message in the log.  However, if you try a DROP TABLE statement from SQL, you will get an error and your SQL step will halt.  I use PROC DELETE all the time when creating new tables in my ETL scripts that load into external databases like Teradata and Oracle.

Long-winded, I know, but I hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

Regarding whether datasets or sql is faster at deleting tables, I investigated that issue a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802599).  `Proc SQL` was generally faster, which was surprising to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can delete the SAS datasets in the work library;

proc datasets lib=work memtype=data kill;
run;

quit;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find that `PROC DELETE` has not gone away and will not anytime soon. Moreover, it is often faster than the `PROC DATASETS ... DELETE` form of deletion for some types of libraries. In my experience, data libraries managed by SPDS with many datasets can cause `PROC DATASETS` of any kind to have very poor performance, and so I will *always* use `PROC DELETE`.